# How to make an app accessable over the internet using Ingress or metalLB on bare metal

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, metallb, bare-metal-server

I'm running a k8s cluter with one control and one worker node on bare metal ubuntu machines (IPs: 123.223.149.27 and 22.36.211.68).

I deployed a sample app:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
kubectl expose deploy nginx --port 80 --target-port 80 --type NodePort
```

Running `kubectl get services` shows me:

```
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        5d23h
nginx          NodePort       10.100.107.184   <none>        80:30799/TCP   5h48m
```

and I can access this appllication inside of the cluster by

```
kubectl run alpine --image=alpine --restart=Never --rm -it -- wget -O- 10.100.107.184:80
```

But now I want to access the sample app outside of the cluster in the internet via `http://123.223.149.27` or later within the domain `mywebsite.com` as the DNS of the domain is pointing to `123.223.149.27`.

I applied:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.12.1/manifests/namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.12.1/manifests/metallb.yaml
```

with this config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: production-public-ips
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 123.223.149.27/32
      - 22.36.211.68/32
```

and this ingress:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.3.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

For me it is not clear, if I have to use ingress (then I would use ingress-nginx) and metalLB and how to configure both. I read a lot of service types like loadBalancer and NodePorts, but I think I didn't understand the concept correctly. I even didn't understand if I have to use ingress-nginx OR metalLB OR both of them. I only understand that if I'm using type LoadBalancer I have to use a loadbalancer as I am on bare metal, so in that case I have to use metalLB.

It would be very helpful for my understanding, if someone could explain on this example app how to make this accessable over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have a running service inside your Kubernetes cluster, you can expose via an ingress-controller which is a reverse-proxy that routes traffics from outside to your dedicated service(s) inside the cluster,

We'll use for example `ingress-nginx`,See  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

These are the requirements you'll need for reaching your service at `mywebsite.com`:

1. Have access to DNS records of your domain `mywebsite.com`
2. Install `ingress-nginx` in your Cluster, See https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx

Install it using `helm`

```bash
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --version $VERSIONS
```

You can look for versions compatibles with your Kubernetes cluster version using:

```bash
helm search repo ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --versions
```

When installation is well finished, you should see ingress-controller service that holds an `$EXTERNAL-IP`

```bash
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                                  AGE

ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.XXX.XXX   XX.XXX.XXX.XX   80:30578/TCP,443:31874/TCP               548d
```

1. Now that you have a running ingress controller, you need to create a `ingress` object that manages external access to your `$Service`,

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

For example:

```yaml
#ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    #cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mywebsite.com
      #secretName: cert-wildcard # get it from certificate.yaml
  rules:
    - host: mywebsite.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: / #/?(.*) #/(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: $Service
                port:
                  number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

4. As you saw in the `ingress` file, commented lines refere to the usage of an SSL certificate generated by `cert-manager` from `LetsEncrypt`, this can be achieved by another process which is described here https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/,
   it depends mainly on your cloud provider (Cloudflare, Azure, ...)
5. Finally, In your DNS zone, Add a DNS record which maps `mywebsite.com` to $EXTERNAL-IP, wait a few minutes and you should be able to access your service under `mywebsite.com`

Comment: But to get external access / external IP, I do need a load balancer, right? So there is a need of another machine, which forwards every request to the clusters ingress

Comment: Ingress plays here the role of a LoadBalancer, if you want to omit using an ingress , you can set your Service type to LoadBalancer , which will expose it under an external IP ( that you can map with your domain ) , but the latter method is no recommended for production practises